# Quantifiers inside a positive look-behind using Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

I am trying to capture a group only if the lookbehind positive criteria satisfies.

Input string is either of the below

1. Cats 5A, 5B and 5C
2. Cat 5A

**Regex**:

1. `(?P<cat_num>(?:(?<=((\b[c|C]at)[s]? )))5A)`  ==> Incorrect because of quantifier present in lookbehind.
2. `(?P<cat_num>(?:(?<=((\b[c|C]at)(?=[s]?) )))5A)`  ==> Correct but does not match "5A" when `Input 1` is given.

**Requirement**:

Using Python regex, I want to capture "5A" in capturing group `cat_num` when any of the above two inputs are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a lookbehind assertion. You could match what comes before the number, and capture the value in the named capturing group `cat_num`

Make the s optional using `[cC]ats?`

```
\b[cC]ats? (?P<cat_num>5A)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/smmD10/1)

Or a bit broader match:

```
\b[cC]ats? (?P<cat_num>\d+[A-Z]+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IeTopa/1)